# unable to install mysql cluster 5.7.6 on windows

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me? I want to install mysql cluster 7.5.6 on my windows but whenever i run the setup.bat as administrator, it always show "web server already running" and then suddenly closed by itself. Is there any solution for this problem? Thanks

Comment: if you run setup.bat and it says it's running then surely it's already installed?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs before i got that error, whenever i run setup.bat, the web page that allow me to create the new cluster will opened. But now it won't appear.

Comment: hm, weeird - check your processes to see if mysql is already running, if so, force kill that process and try again :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a script called setup-debug.bat also available. Running this will give more information about what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably old mcc.pid remained in root. Locate the file and delete it manually, no harm in that. Then try starting MCC again.